# Exclude xvalue in (3d) bar chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, charts

I have the 3d bar chart below:
[image]

Was wondering if there's a way that I can exclude the 'Closed' and 'TOTALS' row in the chart?

Here's my code that generates this:

```
chtOverview.DataSource = dt;

var headercountries = new List<string>();
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
     if (!(dc.ColumnName.ToLower().Contains("total") || dc.ColumnName.ToLower().Contains("status")))
     {
        headercountries.Add(dc.ColumnName);
        chtOverview.Series.Add(new Series(dc.ColumnName));
     }
}

chtOverview.Legends.Add(new Legend("Legend1"));

for (int i = 0; i < headercountries.Count; i++)
{
        chtOverview.Series[i].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        chtOverview.Series[i].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        chtOverview.Series[i].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        chtOverview.Series[i].Legend = "Legend1";
        chtOverview.Series[i].XValueMember = "Case Status";
        chtOverview.Series[i].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        chtOverview.Series[i].YValueMembers = headercountries[i];
}


chtOverview.DataBind();
```

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line where you declare the datasource:

```
chtOverview.DataSource = dt.Select("[Case Status] NOT IN ('Closed', 'TOTALS')");
```